# AWS CDK assets docker bundling

Tags: amazon-web-services, assets, aws-cdk

I am using a Docker-based bundling option to install necessary dependencies and create a Lambda Layer. The deployment succeeds. If I try to deploy a few more times - the bundling is initiated, however, in the end, it states "No changes". And this is expected behavior, since I haven't changed anything, no changes are introduced.

Now the real hocus-pocus happens is when I run the deployment command in a CI/CD pipeline which installs a fresh environment every time. The CDK gets confused and even though no changes to the asset are introduced, it redeploys my layer every single time.

The Question
What do I have to do in order to have deployments only when the changes are introduced to the asset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When bundling artifacts CDK hashes the files in the artifact, if the hash doesn't match then it believes changes have been made and re-uploaded the artifacts.

You can either figure out what's causing the hash to rotate...if subsequent `cdk deploy` invocations locally don't rotate the hash it's probably because of something you *should* be caching in your CI/CD pipeline (like the download of the dependencies)

OR

You can specify your own hash:

```js
const sha = crypto.createHash('sha256');
const dirents = fs.readdirSync(codepath, { withFileTypes: true });
const filesNames = dirents
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isFile())
    .filter(dirent => new RegExp('(.*\.go)|(.*\.(mod|sum))$').test(dirent.name))
    .map(dirent => dirent.name);

for (const file of filesNames) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(codepath, file));
    sha.update(`<file name=${file}>`);
    sha.update(data);
    sha.update('</file>');
}

const codeHash = sha.digest('hex');

lambda.Code.fromAsset(basePath, {
    assetHashType: cdk.AssetHashType.CUSTOM,
    assetHash: codeHash,
    bundling: { // whatever you're doing today
```